# Web scraping in python not loading the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, nsepy

I am trying to get data from NSE website using the below python code and i am getting

```
[<span class="bold" id="orderBookTradeTMC">-</span>]
```

insted of

```
[<span class="bold" id="orderBookTradeTMC">266</span>]
```

the data 266 is not loading
please advice

```
import requests
import bs4
url="https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ITC"
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
   Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup=   bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
print(soup.find_all(id='orderBookTradeTMC'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. You can use `requests` module to simulate it.

For example:

```
import json
import requests


url="https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ITC"
api_url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol={symbol}&section=trade_info'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',}

symbol = url.split('=')[-1]
data = requests.get(api_url.format(symbol=symbol), headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print('Total market capitalization:', data['marketDeptOrderBook']['tradeInfo']['totalMarketCap'])
```

Prints:

```
Total market capitalization: 24082488.32
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Xpath for finding. I am not getting access to the server otherwise i was wishing to check myself.